# Python : Flatten xml to csv with parent tag repeated in child

Tags: python, xml

My xml looks like below.

```
<RootTag xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Branch>
<BranchID>100</BranchID>
   <Child>
        <policy1>hello</policy1>
        <policy2>how are you</policy2>
   </Child>
   <Child>
        <policy1>hello1</policy1>
        <policy2>how are you1</policy2>
   </Child>
</Branch>
<Branch>
<BranchID>200</BranchID>
<Child>
        <policy1>I am good</policy1>
        <policy2>how about you</policy2>
</Child>
<Child>
        <policy1>I am good1</policy1>
        <policy2>how about you1</policy2>
</Child>
</Branch>
</RootTag>
```

I tried using getiterator(beacuse I'm in python 2.6) to get all the elements. I am able to flatten them but the parent tag(BranchID) values should be present in all the rows of its child.

### Output expected:

```
BranchID,policy1,policy2
100,hello,how are you
100,hello1,how are you1
200,I am good,how about you
200,I am good1,how about you1
```

Comment: should both BranchID element really be siblings under the same Branch element? or each should have its own parent Branch element?

Comment: They have their own parent branch. I have updated the xml, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: OK, Great, I'm posting a solution, let me now if it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this code (remember to replace `YOUR FILE HERE` with an actual file path):

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('YOUR FILE HERE')  # replace file name

print("BranchID,policy1,policy2")
branches = root.findall('.//Branch')
for branch in branches:
    branch_id = branch.find("BranchID").text
    for child in branch.findall('.//Child'):
        policy1 = child.find('policy1').text
        policy2 = child.find('policy2').text
        print("{},{},{}".format(branch_id,policy1,policy2))
```

Comment: is it possible to findout the tag name on the fly, instead of hardcoding inside find. For example, instead of specifying "Policy1", is there any way to autofind the tag name, I'm trying to do a generic parser.